# Как сохранить лист типа Sprite в Unity 2d, чтобы после перезахода он не обнулялся

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Спасибо что зашёл на мой вопрос!

У меня такая проблема. В общем у меня есть публичный лист BlueCardsYouHave типа Sprite, и элементы этого листа я добавляю в инспекторе. Ну то есть просто беру спрайт и перетягиваю его на лист.

Кратко поясню: Я делаю игру по типу "Правда или Действие" и этот лист это картинки карточек с действиями которые тебе могу выпасть. А также есть магазин, где за денюшки ты можешь купить набор карточек которые сразу добавится в этот лист BlueCardsYouHave. Ну то есть для примера, по дефолту у тебя 10 карт, ты в магазине купил ещё 5 и у тебя в нём стало 15. И мне нужно чтобы после перезахода в игру вот этот лист BlueCardsYouHave где 15 карт, сохранялся где-то и потом когда заходишь в игру то он загружался из сохранения.

Я до этого знал только способ сохранения через PlayerPrefs, но он слишком примитивный для Sprite Листа. А потом мне пришлось разбираться в сохранении через Json, но и там проблема. Помогите чем сможете пожалуйста

Comment: Примитивные не `PlayerPrefs` или `Json`, а твои представления о данных и программирование в целом. Заблуждаешься ты далеко не только в этом, но и всём остальном, что понаписал. Кстати `Unity2D` не существует. Тебе никто не станет отвечать, потому что нет смысла, ты с основами не знаком. Это прекрасно, что ты пытаешься реализовать свои задумки, так и учатся, но это тот случай, когда нужно сделать шаг назад. Конкретно в данном случае тебя губит то, что ты не знаком с `Single Responsibility Principle` и если желаешь развиваться в программирование, самое время!

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ваше мнение. Я обязательно ознакомлюсь с Single Responsibility Principle. Но кстати насчёт примитивности было неправильно мною сказано да. Потому-что всё таки PlayerPrefs справился с моей задачей, и теперь всё работает как надо